# SQL - Info from multiple tables with two variants of the same field.

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hi guys i'm trying select fields from two tables and display one of the field twice based on a conditional, basicly I need:

```
wp_cimy_uef_data.VALUE WHERE wp_cimy_uef_data.FIELD_ID = 3
wp_cimy_uef_data.VALUE WHERE wp_cimy_uef_data.FIELD_ID = 4
wp_users.user_email
```

I know I have to Join the table's and I think I have done that right, but I have no Idea how to select the VALUE field twice based on a WHERE so far I have:

```
SELECT wp_cimy_uef_data.VALUE, wp_users.user_email, FROM wp_users JOIN wp_cimy_uef_data ON wp_users.ID = wp_cimy_uef_data.USER_ID
```

I though maybe it would be something like

```
SELECT (wp_cimy_uef_data.VALUE WHERE wp_cimy_uef_data.FIELD_ID = 3), (wp_cimy_uef_data.VALUE WHERE wp_cimy_uef_data.FIELD_ID = 4)
```

but obviously that was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do what you want with two joins:

```
SELECT d3.VALUE, d4.value, u.user_email
FROM wp_users u JOIN
     wp_cimy_uef_data d3
     ON u.ID = d3.USER_ID and d3.field_id = 3 JOIN
     wp_cimy_uef_data d4
     ON u.ID = d4.USER_ID and d4.field_id = 4;
```

Note the use of table aliases to distinguish between the two versions of the table.

Comment: i think you're on the right track and understand what im looking to do.... but its giving me an error. I have never used alias's before this do I have to define them somewhere or is it automatic?

Comment: @ShoutItWebSolutions . . . It is automatic.  What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp_users u JOIN
     wp_cimy_uef_data d3
     ON u.ID = d3.USER_ID and d3.f' at line 2  maybe im joining the tables incorrectly... using the wrong key's or something?

Comment: the answer below from M Khalid Junaid worked but returned multiple instances of each record if that gives you an Idea of what might be wrong

Comment: @ShoutItWebSolutions . . . There was a comma before the `from` in your original query, which I hadn't removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`case`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

```
SELECT 
 case when d.FIELD_ID = 3 then d.VALUE end val1,
 case when d.FIELD_ID = 4 then d.VALUE end  val2,
 u.user_email
FROM wp_users u
JOIN wp_cimy_uef_data d ON u.ID = d.USER_ID
```

Use `max` to pick the non null value

```
SELECT 
 max(case when d.FIELD_ID = 3 then d.VALUE end) val1,
 max(case when d.FIELD_ID = 4 then d.VALUE end)  val2,
 u.user_email
FROM wp_users u
JOIN wp_cimy_uef_data d ON u.ID = d.USER_ID 
GROUP BY  u.user_email /* or put  group by u.ID*/
```

Comment: @M_Khalid_Junaid that worked but now its returning multiple copies of each record? is there something wrong with my join?

Comment: @ShoutItWebSolutions see my second query